# Jquery keep track of checkboxes changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have several checkboxes, and depending on how many are selected, I need a message to appear on the screen:

```
<div class="container">

<h2>Pick you toppings (3 max):</h2>

<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one"> Option 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two"> Option 2<br>        
<input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three"> Option 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="four" id="four"> Option 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="five" id="five"> Option 5<br>
</div>

<div class="submited">

<button id="submit">Submit!</button>

<p></p>
</div>
```

The idea with jquery is that when no checkboxes are checked a message should show (between the `<p>`'s) that we need to pick at least 1. we can pix a max of 3 options, and options 4 and 5 can't be picked at the same time.

Once we press submit, a alert should pop up with either the error (if that is the case) or success (if none of the above conditions happens).

I can't seem to get the javascript part to work though..

this is what I have so far:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {

if($(":checkbox:checked").length > 3){
$('p').html("You can not pick more than 3")

} else if ($(":checkbox:checked").length < 1){
$('p').html("Pick at least 1")

} else if ($('#four').is(':checked') && $('#five').is(':checked')){
$('p').html("Can not pick those 2")

} else{
$('p').html("hmmm")
}
```

});

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/npccoLfm/. What's your issue with it?

Comment: What you want to do ?

Comment: just check whether you have jQuery properly loading or not. Because you code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>Pick you toppings (3 max):</h2>

<input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one"> Option 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two"> Option 2<br>        
<input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three"> Option 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="four" id="four"> Option 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="five" id="five"> Option 5<br>
</div>

<div class="submited">

<button id="submit" onclick="check()">Submit!</button>

<p></p>
</div>      

<script>
function check(){
                if($(":checkbox:checked").length > 3){
                    alert("too much box checked.");
                } else if ($(":checkbox:checked").length < 1){
                    alert("not enought box check.")

                } else if ($('#four').is(':checked') && $('#five').is(':checked')){
                    alert("can't choose the five and the fourth box in the same time.")

                } else{
                    alert("Works!")
                }
            }
</script>
```

Your code seems good, but if you want an alert like a pop up you can use this. Can you more explain what you want if this answer doesn't help you, please

Comment: Thanks! For some reason when I tested the code, the messages wouldn't appear. But now they are (I changed nothing :S ).
The pop up should only appear when I click the submit button. (I'm doing that part now). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var len = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
           if(len > 3){
           $("p").html("Select a max of 3");
           }
           else if (len == 0){
           $("p").html("Select at least one");
           }
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it wasn't working when I tested it, but now it's working fine.